# Why can't I create multiple GsonBuilder and register different type adapters for each one?

Tags: java, gson, retrofit

I was using the Retrofit library in conjunction with Gson, and tried this initially:

```
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Dog.class, new Dog.Deserializer());
    Gson dogGson = builder.create();

    builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Cat.class, new Cat.Deserializer());
    Gson catGson = builder.create();

    builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Owl.class, new Owl.Deserializer());
    Gson owlGson = builder.create();


    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(buildType.apiEndpoint)
            .addConverterFactory(new StringConverterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(dogGson))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(catGson))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(owlGson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```

But the deserializers for `Cat` and `Owl` didn't work, only `Dog`'s deserializer was properly getting called. After tinkering around, I tried this:

```
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Dog.class, new Dog.Deserializer());
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Cat.class, new Cat.Deserializer());
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Owl.class, new Owl.Deserializer());
    Gson deserializerGson = builder.create();


    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(buildType.apiEndpoint)
            .addConverterFactory(new StringConverterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(deserializerGson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```

That worked but left me baffled as to why the first way wasn't working. Can I not create multiple `GsonBuilder`s? What's going on here?

Comment: You are not alone, I have just experienced the same here!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple GsonBuilders - that part of your code works like you'd expect. It looks to me like the problem is likely in adding multiple of the same type of ConverterFactory to your Retrofit Builder. When your Retrofit needs to convert some json to an object, it looks through the list of it's Converters, and picks out the the first one that can handle Gson. (The one with the Dog Deserializer, in this case.)

Comment: ah, that makes sense